# Do you know what could be causing my azure function app to throw a 503 error after running 30 seconds?

Tags: azure, function

` [FunctionName("FileShareDirRead02")]
public static async Task Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get","post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)

```
    {   
        //Get the contents of the POST and store them into local variables  
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

        //The following variable values are being passed in to the function through HTTP POST, or via parameters specified in the data factory pipeline
        string storageAccount = data.storageAccount; //Name of storage account containing the fileshare you plan to parse and remove files
        string fileshare = data.fileShare;  //Name of the fileshare within the storage account
        string folderPath = data.folderPath;  // with no leading slash, this will be considered the ROOT of the fileshare. Parsing only goes down from here, never up.
        string keyVaultName = data.keyvaultName; //Name of the key valut where the storage SAS token is stored
        int daysoldbeforeDeletion = data.daysoldbeforeDeletion;  //Number of days old a file must be before it is deleted from the fileshare
        string nameofSASToken = data.nameofsasToken;  //Name of SAS token created through PowerShell prior to execution of this function

        string storageAccountSAS = storageAccount + "-" + nameofSASToken; //Format of the storage account SAS name
        string kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net/";  //URI to the key vault
       
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());  //Instantiate an instance of a SecretClient using the key vault URI
        var storageKey1 = await client.GetSecretAsync(storageAccountSAS);  //Obtain SAS Token from key vault

        string key = storageKey1.Value.Value;   //Assign key the SIG value which is part of the SAS Token
        key = key.Substring(1);  //Trim the leading question mark from the key value since it is not a part of the key

        string connectionString = "FileEndpoint=https://" + storageAccount + ".file.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=" + key;   //Define the connection string to be used when creating a Share Client
        ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString,fileshare);  // Instantiate a ShareClient which will be used to manipulate the file share
        
        var folders = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();  //reference a new list 2-tuple named folders which will include our directories from our share in our Azure Storage Account
        ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(folderPath);   // Get a reference to the directory supplied in the POST
        
        Queue<ShareDirectoryClient> remaining = new Queue<ShareDirectoryClient>();  // Track the remaining directories to walk, starting from the folder path provided in the POST
        remaining.Enqueue(directory);
            while (remaining.Count > 0) // Keep scanning until all folders and files have been evaluated
            {
                ShareDirectoryClient dir = remaining.Dequeue(); // Get all of the next directory's files and subdirectories
                if (dir.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync() != null) //Make sure the folder path exists in the fileshare
                {
                    //return new OkObjectResult("{\"childItems\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(remaining.Count) + "}");  //Returns a list of all files which were removed from the fileshare
                    await foreach (ShareFileItem item in dir.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync())  //For each directory and file
                    {
                            if (!(item.IsDirectory))  //Make sure the item is not a directory before executing the below code
                            {
                                ShareFileClient fileClient = new ShareFileClient(connectionString, fileshare, dir.Path + "/" + item.Name);  //Create the File Service Client
                                if (fileClient.Exists())
                                {
                                    ShareFileProperties properties = await fileClient.GetPropertiesAsync();   //Get the properties of the current file
                                    DateTime convertedtime = properties.LastModified.DateTime;  //Get the last modified date and time of the current file
                                    DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;  //Get today's date and time
                                    TimeSpan timeSpan = date.Subtract(convertedtime);  //Subtract last modified date/time from today's date/time
                                    int dayssincelastmodified = timeSpan.Days;   //Assign the number of days between the two dates
                                    if (dayssincelastmodified > daysoldbeforeDeletion)
                                    {
                                        folders.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(item.Name, fileClient.Path));  // Add the directory names and filenames to our list 2-tuple
                                        fileClient.Delete();  //Delete the file from the share
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (item.IsDirectory)  // Keep walking down directories
                            {
                                remaining.Enqueue(dir.GetSubdirectoryClient(item.Name));
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            return new OkObjectResult("{\"childItems\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folders) + "}");  //Returns a list of all files which were removed from the fileshare
    }
}
```

}`I have written a function app using MS Visual Studio C# and published it to an azure function app. The app is very simple. It reads a directory and all subdirectories of a file share looking for files that have not been modified in the last 90 days. If so, the files are deleted. This function works fine when reading a small set of directories and files. But when I run it on a directory with say a 1000 or more files, the app crashes with a 503 error saying the service is not available and to check back later. I am using an App Service Plan, Standard. I thought maybe it was timing out but this type of plan is not supposed to prevent an app from running, no matter how long it runs. To be sure, I put a line in my host.json file "functionTimeout": "01:00:00" to make sure that was not the problem. I cannot find a single log entry that explains what is happening. Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is a limit for execution time of Azure functions of how long a Function of code can run. This execution time was limited by a hard limit originally set to 5 minutes for consumption plan. Is your function taking more than 5 mins?

Comment: I just had a thought tonight.  We’re you coding and deploying this from a MacBook with an M1 chip set?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is often caused by application-level issues, such as:

- requests taking a long time
- application using high memory/CPU
- application crashing due to an exception.

Seems like your function is taking more time to return an HTTP response. As mentioned in the documentation, 230 seconds is the maximum amount of time that an HTTP triggered function can take to respond to a request. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Also, It is also possible to prevent the autorun of the Azure function by specifying the proper value for the parameter `functionTimeout` of the `host.json` file and where you set the `functionTimeout` to 1 hour.

To debug this issue, refer this [azure-app-service-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) MSFT documentation and follow the troubleshooting steps provided.

**For longer processing times, use Azure Durable Functions async pattern. Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#async-http).**

Comment: I am not hitting the HTTP response timeout since that is 230 seconds, and my app if failing only after 30 seconds. I am using an App Service Plan, which is not supposed to timeout. I actually do not think that is the issue since the app only runs about 30 seconds.  I suspect this has something to do with performance but I also setup Auto Scale with 3 additional nodes and it made no difference at all. Then I scaled up the machine type to the biggest available and auto scaled that to 10. Same problem.

Comment: @Tim, have you gone through the troubleshooting steps, it contains few issue-resolutions!

Comment: Yes, I have been through the trouble shooting tips but they were not helpful. Its very difficult to even find any mention of the problem in the log files. The app is not throwing an exception, it is not taking the 230 seconds to respond, its set to run indefinitely in the host.json file. I also tried adding additional worker nodes and that did not improve the performance. It still stopped at almost the exact same time as before.